# Send custom location

Tags: glympse

For Battery Reasons and to still a requirement I like to have influence on the location send via the Glympse API. Is there a way to set a custom Location Manager feeding Glympse with the locations? I have another GPS device where I get my location updates and like to use these.

If not I like to create this as a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality is not currently provided through SDK Lite. Most of features like that were not included in SDK lite to simplify the API. We are considering extending it in future. Thanks for your request.

However, such API exists in our Commercial SDK. You can find more information about it here:
https://developer.glympse.com/comparison